# Get origin IP in iptable / ufw

Tags: firewall, cloudflare

I have a site on Cloudflare.
I would like to set up an iptable firewall on the server in addition to Cloudflare, to implement rate limiting (Cloudflare have a paid option ...)

Problem: The IP received in IPtable is a Cloudflare IP.

How to recover the real IP of the users in an IPTable rule? From the reverse proxy

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the case of a revese proxy, all connections will originate from the proxy, and the original client IP is transmitted in the HTTP headers, which are on higher level than `iptables` is on. There was a layer7 extension for `iptables`, but to my knowledge it is now abandoned.

So if you don't want to pay for it, you need to look for products which can do layer7 filtering for you, but with `iptables` alone, you are probably out of luck.